# bzcat to delete compressed file

Tags: command-line, delete, bzip2, decompression

By default, `bzcat` (or, equivalently, `bzip2 -dc` or `bunzip2 -c`) will keep the source (compressed file) and not delete it. Is there a flag or other means (besides thereafter manually `rm`ing the file) to delete the compressed file when using `bzcat` or one of its equivalent commands?

(The reason I want to do this — in case you're wondering — is that I wish to `sed`-modify the output for immediate use after `tee`ing the unmodified output to a file. I can of course instead `bzcat | sed ; bunzip2`, but that requires two decompressions. Any other solution for my [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) is certainly welcome in lieu of an answer to the question I pose above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

> bzcat file | tee no_modifications | sed blah blah

?

This would decompress, tee (or split the data) into a file call no_modifications and stdout which you pipe into sed for "immediate use".

If you really want to delete the original then I'm afraid you're down to

> bzcat file | tee no_modifications | sed blah blah && rm file

Comment: So your answer is "No, there's no such means". Okay, thanks! Any support you can provide for that claim would boost its reliability.

Comment: bzip2.c line 1298 only file to file mode even checks keepInputFiles  set by the argument parser.